# Connect from FB3.0 to FB2.5

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, firebird-3.0

I had 2 servers that were using Firebird 2.5. Each of the servers had a separate database and one of them was connecting to the other one to retrieve some data. One of the servers switched to Firebird 3.0 and now it can't connect to the 2.5 server. It says my Username or Password is incorrect. I've connected to the 2.5 server with the credentials and they are ok.

To retrieve data I was using Execute statement [STATEMENT] on external Datasource [SERVER] as user [USER] password [PASSWORD].

The 2.5 has more databases and it would be a hassle to upgrade it to 3.0.

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: What is the configuration of `AuthClient` and `WireCrypt` in the Firebird 3.0 `firebird.conf` file? Exactly which versions of Firebird 3 and Firebird 2.5 are you using? Also, please provide the exact error message.

Comment: `The 2.5 has more databases and it would be a hassle to upgrade it to 3.0.` - you can have both 3.0 and 2.5 running on that computer, convert the database you need connection to to FB3, while other databases my remain on 2.5 until you would find time to convert them too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done some testing with a Firebird 2.5 (2.5.8) and Firebird 3 (3.0.4) on the same server with different ports using the following simple statement (and modifying some parts depending on what I'm testing) to see what kind of connection failures I can produce.

```sql
set term #;
execute block returns (tblname char(31))
as
begin
  for execute statement 'select rdb$relation_name from rdb$relations where coalesce(rdb$system_flag, 0) = 0' 
    on external data source 'localhost/3051:D:\data\db\testdatabase.fdb' 
      as user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey'
    into tblname
  do suspend;
end#
set term ;#
```

## Firebird 3 to Firebird 2.5

Using this statement, I can get error *"Your user name and password are not defined."* from Firebird 3 to 2.5 in the following situations:

1. Firebird 3 has a `AuthClient`<sup>1</sup> configuration that does not include `Legacy_Auth`. Firebird 3 cannot authenticate to Firebird 2.5 as Firebird 2.5 only knows about the legacy authentication mechanism.

   To fix this, add `Legacy_Auth` to the `AuthClient` setting in `firebird.conf` of the Firebird 3 server (for example set it to `AuthClient = Srp, Legacy_Auth`) and restart the server.

   This point is most likely your problem.
2. Not specifying username and password (ie leaving `as user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey'` out of the `execute statement`). This is probably due to the difference in authentication mechanisms as Firebird doesn't know the actual password with the SRP protocol and therefor will not be able to authenticate to the other server.

   Specifying a username and password fixes this.

## Firebird 2.5 to Firebird 3

In reverse direction (Firebird 2.5 to 3), I cannot establish a connection in the following situations:

1. Authenticating with a username and password that exists only as a Srp user. This results in error *"Your user name and password are not defined."* as Firebird 2.5 only supports the legacy authentication, and as a result can only authenticate with users that exists for the Legacy_UserManager plugin in Firebird 3.

   Create a user (either with the same name or a different name) for the Legacy_UserManager plugin:

   ```sql
   create user theuser password 'thepassword' using plugin Legacy_UserManager;
   commit;
   ```

   If this results in error *"Missing requested management plugin"*, then you need to edit the Firebird 3 `firebird.conf` and add `Legacy_UserManager` to the `UserManager` setting (eg set to `UserManager = Srp, Legacy_UserManager`; the default is only `Srp`) and restart Firebird.

   As SYSDBA you can check on the Firebird 3 server for which plugin (or plugins!) a user exists by executing

   ```sql
   select SEC$USER_NAME, SEC$PLUGIN 
   from SEC$USERS
   ```
2. Firebird 3 has setting `WireCrypt = Required` (this is the default!). This produces the error *"connection rejected by remote interface"*.

   To fix this, set `WireCrypt = Enabled` in the `firebird.conf` of the Firebird 3 server and restart the server.
3. Not specifying username and password (ie leaving `as user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey'` out of the `execute statement`). This produces an error *"unknown ISC error 335545106"* (actual message is *"Error occurred during login, please check server firebird.log for details"* if a Firebird 3 message file is used) where the log of Firebird 3 says *"No matching plugins on server"*, this is probably due to the difference in authentication mechanisms.

   Specifying a username and password fixes this.
4. Firebird 3 has a `AuthServer` configuration that does not include `Legacy_Auth` (the default is `Srp` only!). This also produces error *"unknown ISC error 335545106"* (actual message is *"Error occurred during login, please check server firebird.log for details"* if a Firebird 3 message file is used) where the log of Firebird 3 says *"No matching plugins on server"*.

   To fix this, add `Legacy_Auth` to the `AuthServer` setting in `firebird.conf` of the Firebird 3 server (for example set it to `AuthServer = Srp, Legacy_Auth`) and restart the server.

And, of course, in both directions error *"Your user name and password are not defined."* can also be produced by using non-existent users or wrong passwords.

---

<sup>1. The setting `AuthClient` is relevant here as the server is acting as a client when executing an `execute statement ... on external data source ...`</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was in the 3.0 in firebird.conf at AuthClient just as you suggested. It was set to Srp and we set in to Srp, Win_Sspi, and Legacy_Auth. Now it works perfactly.